# How to fix disk state to boot

Tags: dual-boot, disk

I try to find my own solution but because of lack of key words I havent been able to.

My computer has a solid state disk, and a 2000 gig regular disk.  The solid state has two main partitions, one for windows and the other for linux 14.04.  the 2000 gig HD is where i store store my files, and access them via Ubuntu or Windows.

Everything was working fine, until I tried to set up the 2000 gig HD to auto mount at start up/boot.  I tried to use the disks utlility, and seclected the edit mount option for the partition I wanted.  The first option, automatic mount option gives on-off option, but the instructions I followed made it seem as if in off it was active, and on was not.  I made the changes, and rebooted (Automatic mout options was set to off).

I was expececting to reboot and see the partition mount by itself, instead I am now not able to boot ubuntu or windows.

If I try ubuntu it just goes onto a black screen, i left it for over 3 hours and nothing.  If I did a ctrl alt del it reboots

Same thing happens when I try windows.  I was able to go into safe mode and I was able to restore to a previous state, however when it boots it just sits there on the windows screen.

I tried a USB Ubuntu.  When I boot up from USB and I try to open the 2000 gig partition it gives an error, basically it has zeros which means it wasn{t shut down properly.  I use a fixnfts command and I am able to access.

I am hoping there is a way I can recover without having to start from scratch.

One last problem.  My ubuntu system was encrypted, how could I retrive files if I do end up having to re install ubuntu

Comment: Are you able to now successfully boot into Windows and see the 2TB disk? If so, I'll assume it's your D: drive. Open an Administration Command Prompt window, and type **chkdsk c: /f** to check out the file system on D:. If it checks out OK, try and boot into Ubuntu. Report back. Cheers, Al

Comment: No, I was able to start and finish a windows restore, but it still won{t boot.  I can only get into safe mode.  I did go in safe mode and try to run chkdsk /f but says it has to reschedule it as it is being used by another process.  Also in past I have gone in to windows c prompt, and deleted all files in the config folder, and I was able to boot my computer that way.  This time when i try to copy files i am told it is being used by another process.  In safe mode I can view 2000 gig partition.

Comment: Getting worse. Boot into safe mode in Windows. Do a **chkdsk d:/f** to check the 2TB (I had a typo, above). Then do a **chkdsk c:/f** to check your boot drive, and say yes to reschedule, then reboot Windows. Once both C: and D: drives pass chkdsk, try and boot into Ubuntu. Cheers, Al

Comment: I still cant boot Ubuntu or Windows.  I am able to get onto command prompt via windows recovery and run chkdsk on both the 2TB partition, and the windows partition.  After I complete chkdsk if I boot up with Ubuntu USB stick, I am able to mount both partitions without a problem.  I went ahead and unplugged the 2TB hard drive.  Figured once I am up and running I can just add it again.

Comment: I just left Ubuntu starting on the black screen, plan to give it over night to see what happens.  Similar with windows, it goes to the window boot screen, where the little dots of circles goes and goes, and it just goes and goes.  To get out I hace to press and hold power button.  If I boot up with ubuntu USB stick, the NTFS partitions wont mount unless I do a chkdsk first.  Any suggestions

Comment: Strange situation. What you originally did with trying to mount the 2TB in Ubuntu shouldn't have had anything to do with Windows booting... unless something is corrupting the NTFS file systems. I've run out of ideas for you. I'd be curious what you end up doing. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks Heynnema.  Everything was stable until I tured off-on the automatic mount at start up via Disks Utility.  I had been dealing with windows issues, so now not sure if they are related or not.  I am now reading up instructions on how to load my encrypted home folder so I can copy my mail files and then format my Ubuntu partition and start with a fresh install, JOY!

Comment: Good luck! Let us know how you do. Cheers, Al

Comment: I was going to install Ubuntu 16 on a new partition i created.  When I ran it, i noticed it gave me an option to upgrade my 14.04 install instead.  Figured I would try that.  WHen I select upgrade I get this error message The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as an "EFI boot partition" and should be at least 35 MB in size...  IF I had windows and Ubuntu 14.04 running fine, is there a chance that EFI boot partition is the one not letting me boot up?  How can I fix it?

Comment: You didn't change your BIOS from UEFI to CSM/Legacy boot, or the other way around, did you? Post a gparted screenshot of your drive and I'll take a look. Cheers, Al

Comment: Yes, at some point I did start messing around with it, while trying to install onto a USB, etc.  Let me figure out how to post a screen shot and I will post it, thank you again.

Comment: Set it back to UEFI, 'cause that how Windows was installed, and you should install Ubuntu at the same setting. Think back about how you installed 14.04, and you may just have to wipe it out and start all over with a fresh Ubuntu installation. Cheers, Al

Comment: Not sure if the link like this will work, http://imgur.com/b1oPlA5 but that is my gparted. I think Ubuntu was installed on UEFI

Comment: I looked at the gparted map. It's a mess. Don't know where to start. It doesn't have an EFI boot partition, it has a legacy boot partition. If it was me, I'd make sure UEFI boot is enabled in the BIOS, wipe the entire disk, reinstall Windows (to a much smaller partition), reinstall Ubuntu (to a larger partition). Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

After a lengthy discussion in the comments...

It doesn't have an EFI boot partition, it has a legacy boot partition. If it was me, I'd make sure UEFI boot is enabled in the BIOS, wipe the entire disk, reinstall Windows (to a much smaller partition), reinstall Ubuntu (to a larger partition).

Cheers, Al